# About Node-webkit update and upgrade the software

Tags: html, node-webkit

About Node-webkit,I've packed up my files, and generate about HTML5. Nw & exe, I want to know how to remotely update and upgrade the software.
Thanks.
(Sorry,My English is not good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Node Webkit Generator for Yeoman on mac and Linux, you can try replacing the HTML files on the fly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22160360/3232427

However, Windows users will still have to download and replace the exe with the app bundled in it.

Another option is to code a generic HTML/NodeJS app on Node-Webkit, loading/checking the dynamic content from the server and storing it on the Local Storage for offline access.

You will need an abstraction layer to handle that, but this should work on all platforms.